# How to create a custom dataset which will contain the anchor,positive and negative images of LFWPeople Dataset in Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, torchvision, image-classification

I am trying to classify the faces in the LFWPeople dataset by using a siamese network but I don't know how to actually create a proper dataset to  get the anchor,positive,and negative image into my custorm dataset from the LFWPeople dataset.Link to the dataset on the pytorch official site:[https://pytorch.org/vision/main/generated/torchvision.datasets.LFWPeople.html](https://stackoverflow.com)